# What is the application of the SMA connectors on the DE2 115 FPGA board

Tags: fpga, connector, board

The SMA connectors are expected to be used for clock IO. However, the board already has oscillator and the PLLs can be used to generate a variety of clock frequencies. Besides, for any daughter board connected to the extender socket or the HSMC interface, the clock signal can be sent via the connector itself. Why then would someone need to use these SMA connectors?

Comment: SMA connector can be used up to 28 GHz. Some development boards expose a pair of there transceiver signal lines via SMA for testing or to connect yet unknown connectors. For ex. there are SMA to SATA adapters, so you could connect a SATA SSD at 6 Gbps to an FPGA  via SMA :).

Comment: Ok. On a side note, I am writing a vga adapter that is 640x480 at 72Hz. This requires 21.175MHz clock. However with the 50MHz clock, it is not possible to generate this precise 21.175MHz clock by using PLLs. Is it possible top use the closest frequency which is less than 1% off the value of 21.175MHz without breaking anything?

Comment: The VESA spec has some tollerance. In the end it depends on your monitor.

Answer (score 2):

It's a development board, so it is designed to be flexible. Maybe you need a clock that can't be generated from an onboard oscillator with a PLL. Or you need a very low phase noise clock. Or perhaps a variable clock from an RF signal generator or ARB. Or perhaps you need multiple boards to run from the same clock source.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you stated what the DE2 115 board was, and who made it.

However, I'll guess that it is an FPGA demo/evaluation board.  If so, the manufacturer probably put the SMA connectors on the board assuming that some potential users may require them.

Comment: DE** boards a Terrasic boards eqipped with Altera Cyclone or Stratix FPGAs :).

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of applications for SMA clock I/O. You might want to generate a specific clock externally (syncing to an external reference clock, for example; or a variable clock that can't be easily generated via PLL). Additionally, the clock output may be important for chaining device clocks or simply connecting to test equipment to check frequency/jitter/etc.

In all these examples and more, you might not want to use the other connectors; SMA is nice when you need a high frequency signal run over a long length of coax.

Answer (score 0):

The SMA connector is an arbitrary choice for a clock connector and is quite often used on fpga dev boards.  It can be misleading/confusing if your a RF person like me; I've not seen one designed to drive/match 50 ohms, so I would verify any comments or answers that imply that you can do so.  In the likely case that it is not matched, tee with a 50 ohm termination or keep cable short: for example, a 10 MHz clock in coax has roughly 20 meter wavelength so you longest run should be less than 2 meters. A 100 MHz clock should be less than 20 cm.  Despite the designed frequency limit of a SMA connector, you will be limited by the performance of the fpga.